# sidebar untoggle on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm testing on Start Bootstrap's [sidebar template](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/).

The template's jQuery is pretty simple:

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

I'd like the sidebar to be toggled on desktop screens and untoggled on small devices.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });

    function sidebarResize() {
        if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        } else {
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        }
    }
    sidebarResize();
});
```

The document loads and the sidebar is toggled, but it doesn't untoggle when I resize the screen.

How can I achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Use CSS media queries rather than going for a Javascript solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind the function to the window resize event..

`$(window).resize(sidebarResize);`

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/tDdQm8TrB9